# Como publicar em uma pagina do Facebook utilizando a SDK PHP (5.0)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para agendar publicações de hora em hora para minha pagina do Facebook, já consigo efetuar o loguin do usuário obter ID Token de acesso do usuário e  tudo mais, tenho as permissões necessárias no aplicativo do Facebook, e já consegui ate postar mensagens com imagem no perfil do usuário, porém não consegui nada relacionado a paginas, todos os codigos que encontrei não funcionaram.

Preciso obter a lista de paginas que o usuário gerencia, obter o token de acesso(prolongado) de uma determinada pagina e publicar fotos no Facebook com o perfil da pagina (Não quero publicar links, quero publicar apenas imagens com legenda).

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que gerar um **Token** *específico* para página. Tem no Facebook pra fazer isso.

Depois disso são os mesmos processos para fazer um POST num perfil, com a diferença na URL.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
   'app_id'                => [APP_ID],
   'app_secret'            => [APP_SECRET],
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7',
]);

$linkData = [
    'link'          => '',
    'caption'       => '',
    'description'   => '',
    'name'          => '',
    'message'       => '',
    'picture'       => ''
];

$pageAccessToken ='';

try {
    $response = $fb->post('/NOME_DA_PAGE/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui postar utilizando um token obtido na https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ porém este token dura apenas uma hora.

Você sabe como obter um token dentro da própria aplicação?

Comment: Tem um lugar aí que você pega o Token eterno, dá uma lida na página que pega o Token... https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: Essa parada do token eterno pelo que pesquisei foi descontinuada, os tokens atuais duram por aproximadamente dois meses, o token de 2 meses já me ajuda, mas o ideal seria conseguir um token pela própria aplicação,vou continuar pesquisando aqui, muito obrigado!

Comment: Cara, eu uso uma aqui... nunca deu problema, desde junho.

Comment: Tem que clicar no botão **Extends Access Token**. Quando clicar vai aparecer uma frase e um Token. **This new long-lived access token will never expire:**

Comment: Consegui o token de acesso eterno para a pagina, valeu mesmo @Gumball
Você tem resposta para está pergunta > http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172745/como-mencionar-uma-pagina-ou-perfil-do-facebook-com-sdk-php