# Como mencionar uma pagina ou perfil do Facebook com SDK PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk

Como mencionar uma pagina ou perfil do Facebook ao publicar via SDK PHP 5.0?
Ao publicar uma imagem como minha pagina gostaria de marcar o próprio perfil dela na descrição da imagem, algo como "Curtam: Pagina".

Isso é possível?

Comment: Acho que é só colocar @nome_da_pagina que reconhece sozinho. Assim como Hashtag